# How to fix data discrepancy in conversions from Google Ads into Google Bigquery via BigQuery Data Transfer Service for Google Ads

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery Data Transfer Service for Google Ads and I'm seeing data discrepancy for one of our client's conversions. The conversions differ in both conversions and view-through conversions from what I'm getting in Google Ads. Initially, I thought it was perhaps maybe the last 30 days of data not being refreshed, but when I look back in April, I'm still seeing some discrepancy even though May matched up. The weird part is that Google BigQuery has more conversions than what is shown in Google Ads. Wondering if anyone else has this issue and can provide a fix to get accurate reporting. Thanks in advance!

Tried different dates to verify accuracy in data

## Standard SQL

```
SELECT 
  ConversionTypeName, 
  SUM(AllConversions) 
FROM ###.CampaignCrossDeviceConversionStats_######
WHERE (Date BETWEEN '2019-04-01' AND '2019-04-30') AND ConversionAttributionEventType = 'IMPRESSION'
GROUP BY ConversionTypeName
```

I expect the data to match up for the most part except perhaps small discrepancies in the last 30 days since the date refreshes on a 30 day window

Comment: Were you able to find the reason why this happens? I'm also seeing huge differences in conversions between Google Ads and BigQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Discrepancies issues on BigQuery transfers in general, including Google Ads to BigQuery transfers are often resolved by setting up a [backfill](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/working-with-transfers#set_up_a_backfill) for the affected time period.

Other than that, I would recommend you to contact the [Google Ads support](https://support.google.com/google-ads/gethelp).