# Google Ads Impressions count in BigQuery is not the same as in the Google Ads Reports

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery Data Transfer Service for Google Ads and while validating the transferred data by querying it, I noticed discrepancies between what I see in the Google Ads Reports and what has been transferred to BigQuery.
While clicks and cost data is ok, the impression data has dramatically difference.
Is there any way to get impression data in BigQuery close to impression data in Google Ads Reports?
What could be the reason of discrepancies?

My query in the BigQuery:

```
SELECT
  Date,
  SUM(Impressions) as Impressions,
  SUM(Clicks) as Clicks,
  ROUND(SUM(Cost / 1000000), 2) as Cost
  
FROM
  ds_GooAds_517_565_1143.AccountStats_5175651143
WHERE
  True

GROUP BY Date
ORDER BY Date
```

[Google Ads Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZI9p.png)
[BigQuery Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2jn5.png)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the "p_CampaignBasicStats_" table instead of the "p_CampaignStats_".
In the "p_CampaignStats_" table the "ClickType" column splits the data into different parts of an ad which can be clicked, for example sitelinks, url-clicks, etc. It means that several parts of an ad receive an impression with only 1 viewing of the whole ad.
This schema continues also with the other table e.g. account, keyword, ads, ad groups etc.

This workaround took me also long to find. There are some differences between the Big Query Google Ads Data Transfer and the actual data in the Google Ads UI.

Answer (score 0):

The WHERE True part of your code - Does it need to be there? Try to remove this and see if the impressions is correct.
Looks like you are using the Data Transfer service. This data should be correct.

The querying of may not be correct. Try to limit the Dates to a specific time frame that you are sure all the data has been loaded into BigQuery.

Possibly, the reports on Google Ads is using sampled data which for Google Analytics is the case sometimes in why there is a discrepancy between the webpage and BigQuery.

Please also see:

[Transfer Service Data Discrepancy: Google Ads (AdWords) <> BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53566946/transfer-service-data-discrepancy-google-ads-adwords-bigquery)

[How to fix data discrepancy in conversions from Google Ads into Google Bigquery via BigQuery Data Transfer Service for Google Ads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56961926/how-to-fix-data-discrepancy-in-conversions-from-google-ads-into-google-bigquery)

Answer (score 0):

You should use another table(`CampaignBasic` instead of `AccountStats`):

```
SELECT
  Date,
  SUM(Impressions) as Impressions,
  SUM(Clicks) as Clicks,
  ROUND(SUM(Cost / 1000000), 2) as Cost
FROM
  ds_GooAds_517_565_1143.CampaignBasic_5175651143
GROUP BY Date
ORDER BY Date
```

I also faced this problem. And using the `CampaignBasic` table totally solves my problem.